# Rails redirect sending me to localhost:3007

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect

I'm working on a Rails application and i'm having the following problem.

I'm using a gem called Wicked. Basically what the gem does is allow the programmer to define **steps** in a controller and for each **step** in the show action of that controller render a different view.

Something like these

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  steps :one, :two, :three, :four

  def show
    requested_step = params[:id]

    if some_condition
      render_step requested_step
    else
      redirect_to action: "show", id: "four"
    end
  end
end
```

So, you have steps one, two, three, four and you request something like "my_controller/one" that takes the :id as "one" in the controller and renders one.erb for example.

All cool for now.

**BUT**

When i call the redirect_to like in the code above it redirects me to **localhost:3007/my_controller/four**. Yes, port **3007** instead of **3000**. And obviously my site can't reach that URL.

I already checked if i have another server fire up or another process that could be bother and generating this redirect going to port 3007. But it wasn't the case.

Is just this redirect that sends me to 3007. Any other request goes just fine to port 3000.

Any one with a similar problem sometime?

Thanks

My Rails version is 4.2.6

Comment: cano you do a `grep 3007 * -r` in your rails folder to search if anywhere are set this port?

Comment: Thanks, my dev port was set in 3007, but i don't know why it was firing up in 3000, i set it with **rails s -p 3007** and is working now.

Comment: @Mario Consider answering your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that my dev server was set to **localhost:3007**. I didn't realize that because when firing up running **rails s** the server run on **3000** port.

I fire up the server with **rails s -p 3007** and no more problems.

Thanks and sorry i didn't realize it before.

Comment: Great job on answering your own answer. Now, consider accepting your own answer: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/